# How to remove nested object with EF. ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have admin page and have a logic to delete item but for some reason it doesn't work. I have model "Item" and "CartItem".

**Item**

```
public class Item : BaseEntity
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Item Photo")]
        public string ItemPhoto { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Item Type")]
        public string ItemType { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Item Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Item Color")]
        public string Color { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Item Size")]
        public string Size { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Item Material Type")]
        public string MaterialType { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Designed For")]
        public string DesignedFor { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Item Price")]
        public double Price { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Item Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

**CartItem**

```
public class CartItem : BaseEntity
    {
        public Item Item { get; set; }
        public int? UserId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public User User { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteItemPost(int id)
        {
            var item = await _itemRepo.ReadByIdAsync(id);
            if (item == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            await _itemRepo.DeleteAsync(item);
            return RedirectToAction("ReadItems");
        }
```

When i check with debugger everything works fine but item is still in database. After long time of searching i thought that problem was the "CartItem" Model, because "Item" is connected with foreign key. So i am not sure what is the problem here, i don't get any exceptions, any errors or something like that, everything works fine but the object doesn't remove

**Repository**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using RandApp.Data;
using RandApp.Models;
using RandApp.Repositories.Abstraction;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RandApp.Repositories
{
    public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db = default;
        private readonly DbSet<T> _entity = default;
        public Repository(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
            _entity = _db.Set<T>();
        }
        public async Task<bool> CreateAsync(T item)
        {
            _entity.Add(item);
            return await SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public async Task<bool> DeleteAsync(T item)
        {
            _entity.Remove(item);
            return await SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> ReadAsync()
        {
            return await _entity.ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<T> ReadByIdAsync(int? id)
        {
            return await _entity.FirstOrDefaultAsync(o => o.Id == id);
        }

        public async Task<bool> UpdateAsync(T item)
        {
            _entity.Update(item);
            return await SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public async Task<bool> SaveChangesAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                return (await _db.SaveChangesAsync()) >= 0;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public DbSet<T> Get()
        {
            return _entity;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: whether you get the item value in ReadByIdAsync method. Also it is redirected to "ReadItems" without deletion right.

Comment: Check in `itemRepo` I bet something is not committing the transaction in EF.

Comment: @Ramji yes i get item value in ReadByIdAsync method. _itemRepo.DeleteAsync(item) should delete item but i doesn't

Comment: I agree with @beautifulcoder. Is your DeleteAsync method in your item repo saving changes when it is complete?

Comment: @beautifulcoder i thought the same but it seems to be fine. i'll update its code

Comment: @Hedgybeats i updated code and as you can see it saves changes. one weird fact is that when i first wrote code and tested it, it was working fine but now it has some problem i dont know

Answer (score 0):

I see the codes swallows the exception via the try/catch in `SavesChangesAsync` and returns `false`. I would do the following:

1. Nuke the try/catch. Or, log any exceptions so there is visibility
2. Check the return value. If the value is false, something is wrong with the db connection

Comment: your were right, in savechangesasync() method returns false but only in case of delete, i tried other ones and it works perfectly. i am still thinking that as you can see in "CartItem" i have field type of "Item" and "Item" has reference to "CartItem" right? so when i try to delete item, it can't because of foreignKey

Comment: and how can i do it to delete the "cartItem" as well when "Item" is deleted

Comment: I would check the exception message, it will probably tell you about some FK violation.

Comment: it doesn't throw any exception. everything works but there is not result. at this moment i ran code and try to delete item and it worked, item was deleted, then tried again and did nothing... i dont get it what is the problem

Comment: Are you sure? I notice you aren't capturing any exception in the `catch` block. Put a breakpoint where it returns false to make sure. You can query the db to make sure there is something to delete, maybe it is working as intended.

Comment: yes i logged exception and as i said it has problem with FK. CartItem contains ItemId and it is the problem. Despite FK, is there any solution to delete item? i found one way to write some code in OnModelCreating method(in applicationDbContext namespace) but didn't fully understand what and how to do it

Comment: You are gonna need to delete `CartItem` first. Then, the parent entity. Also, why is `Item` the parent entity? It is a one-to-one relationship with `CartItem` as the child.

Comment: you mean in CartItem i shouldnt have Item type param?

Comment: that is the error: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_ShoppingCartItems_ItemsTable_ItemId". The conflict occurred in database "RandDb", table "dbo.ShoppingCartItems", column 'ItemId'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: The item which is not added in cart by any user, deletes without any problem, but the ones which are in shopping cart, throw that error, so the problem seems to be reference between cartItem and Item but i dont know how to solve it